# Как работает index при добавлении записи в mysql

Tags: mysql

Он полностью переиндексирует заново всю таблицу по полю или добавляет в уже существующий индекс новый фрагмент индекса? Вообщем как устроен индекс?
И что лучше 1 таблица на 1 миллион записей или 100 таблиц по 10 тысяч записей(но тогда сложней запросы, например разбивать на страны, но бывает запросы нужно делать из нескольких таблиц сразу так как данные нужно из нескольких стран, или все страны и данные в 1 таблице, как пример...)?

Comment: Со вторым вопросом все просто: если у вас возникает необходимость делать дополнительные таблицы, вам не нужен MySQL. По первому не могу сказать из-за отсутствия достаточной квалификации, но скорее всего просто вставляет новую запись и перестраивает часть дерева.

Comment: @Etki необходимости нет, вопрос подкорректировал.

Comment: Индексы хранятся в виде B-деревьев, идет вставка ключа в индекс, полная перестройка не требуется, может потребоваться перебалансировка дерева, но это ограниченное количество операций. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE  Вполне возможно, что используются алгоритмы близкие к красно-черным деревьям. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Одна таблица на миллион лучше, не представляю как вы будете решать из каких таблиц из 100 выбирать информацию. Для вопросов оптимизации существует портиционирование - разбиение таблиц на разные носители средствами самой БД http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Индексы хранятся в виде [B-деревьев](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), идет вставка ключа в индекс, полная перестройка не требуется, может потребоваться перебалансировка дерева, но это ограниченное количество операций. Вполне возможно, что используются алгоритмы близкие к [красно-черным деревьям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).